# How to implement an atomic counter

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, stdatomic

Trying to make a unique id generating function, and came up with this:

```
std::atomic<int> id{0};
int create_id() {
    id++;
    return id.load();
}
```

But I assume it's possible for that function to return the same value twice, right? For example, thread A calls the function, increments the value, but then halts while thread B comes in and also increments the value, finally A and B both return the same value.

So using mutexes, the function might look like this:

```
std::mutex mx;
int id = 0;
int create_id() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mx};
    return id++;
}
```

My question: Is it possible to create the behavior of spawning unique int values from a counter using only atomics? The reason I'm asking is because I need to spawn a lot of id's, but read that mutex is slow.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Simply use:

```
std::atomic<int> id{};

int create_id() {
    return id++;
}
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith

Comment: By default, std::atomic<int> is uninitialized. Since this particular instance has static storage duration, it is initialized to 0, but if `id` were a field in a class, for instance, it would be necessary to add `{0}` after `std::atomic<int> id`

Comment: Note that there's also this nice `std::atomic_int` alias.

Answer (score 10):

Your two code snippets do two different things.

```
id++;
return id.load();
```

that code increments `id`, then returns the incremented value.

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mx};
return id++;
```

that code returns the value **before** the increment.

The correct code to do what the first tries to do is

```
return ++id;
```

The correct code to do what the second does is

```
return id++;
```

Answer (score 9):

A mutex is overkill.

There is no pre-increment atomic operation (but you can return the
previous value and add one to that, of course).

As pointed out by Pete, your first code block attempts to do
a pre-increment (return the result of the increment).

Doing `return ++id` works, but is equivalent to `return id.`[`fetch_add`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add)`(1) + 1;`
which uses the slow default sequentially-consistent memory order. This is not required here, in fact you can do with a relaxed [memory order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order).

If you really mean to use a global variable for the atomic, the correct (and fastest) code that does what your first code block attempts is:

```
int create_id() {
    static std::atomic<int> id{0};
    return id.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) + 1;
}
```

Notes:

You can leave away the `+ 1` if you want post-increment.

Using `std::memory_relaxed` doesn't make a difference on Intel CPU's (x86) because `fetch_add` is a Read-Modify-Write operation and the bus must be locked anyway (`lock` assembly instruction). But on a more relaxed architecture it *does* make a difference.

I didn't want to pollute global namespace with 'id', so I put it as a static in the function; however in that case you must make sure that on your platform that doesn't lead to actual initialization code. E.g. if a constructor that isn't constexpr needs to be called then a test is necessary to see if the static was already initialized or not. Fortunately, the value initializing constructor of an integral atomic is constexpr, so the above leads to [constant initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization).

Otherwise you'd want to make it -say- a static member of a class that is wrapping this and put the initialization somewhere else.

Comment: in C++ ATOMIC_VAR_INIT is not needed. From the link in your answer: "This macro is primarily provided for compatibility with C; it behaves the same as the constructor of std::atomic."

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. The value-initializing constructor of an atomic is constexpr, so that that leads to a constant-initialization as well. Kinda makes sense because that is how it should be, with a compiler that knows what it is doing ;). I'll update my answer a bit.