# Is there something like ATOMIC_INC in CMSIS for Cortex-M 3 4 7?

Tags: c, arm, stm32, atomic, cortex-m

Cortex M 3 4 7 support LDREX and STREX assembler instructions and with these CMSIS provides for example ATOMIC_MODIFY_REG that ensures an atomic modification of an (u)int32_t (ie clear some bits and set some (maybe other) bits).
Now I thought there also could be equivalently something like ATOMIC_INC and ATOMIC_DEC to atomically increment or decrement an (u)int32_t variable. But there isn't.
Is there something wrong with this idea? I could easily change ATOMIC_MODIFY_REG into ATOMIC_INC but testing if this will really be atomic is not so easy.
I am using STMCubeIDE, latest version.

Thanks for any help

Edit: not sure anymore if ATOMIC_MODIFY_REG is really CMSIS.
here is the ATOMIC_MODIFY_REG I have in STM CubeIDE:

```
    /* Atomic 32-bit register access macro to clear and set one or several bits */
#define ATOMIC_MODIFY_REG(REG, CLEARMSK, SETMASK)                    \
  do {                                                               \
    uint32_t val;                                                    \
    do {                                                             \
      val = (__LDREXW((__IO uint32_t *)&(REG)) & ~(CLEARMSK)) | (SETMASK); \
    } while ((__STREXW(val,(__IO uint32_t *)&(REG))) != 0U);         \
  } while(0)
```

Comment: ldrex/strex were originally intended for multi core systems to manage shared access to resources.  I believe for some of the cores/architectures (cortex-m) these are not exclusive (does it make sense to support them?). You would need different process ids that you can put the processor into in order to have one process set the exclusive bits and another interfere to see that it worked.  How does one do that with the core/chip you have?

Comment: In order to share a resource you need another resource to manage this lock.  the location you want to change and the location used to manage the location.   not that one cant do that in a macro/library.  have you tried to implement this yourself?

Comment: wfe/wfi on some cores is simply a nop.  make sure that it does what you think it does first for your core/chip.  it would not make sense to create macros if the macros do not actually do what is implied, so first off does it do what you think and there has to be a specific systemic way it is used to provide that functionality.

Comment: `ATOMIC_MODIFY_REG` is fine, except it may lock if you have contention.  Generally if there is only mainline and irq on a single cpu, the IRQ win and there is no contention.  Also, it could not be used by external masters.  For instance, attempt to use it on DMA memory as a transfer is in action.

Answer (score 2):

CMSIS 5.1 defines macros/functions for LDREX/STREX functionality.  The macros/functions have variants for 'B'yte, 'H'alfword and 'W'ord.  Ie, LDREXH, STREXB.  It does not use the functionality to implement atomic/lock-free primitives, but you can use them to implement your own.

```
| Instruction  | CMSIS function                      |
| ------------ | ----------------------------------- |
| LDREX        | uint32_t __LDREXW (uint32_t \*addr) |
| LDREXH       | uint16_t __LDREXH (uint16_t \*addr) |
| LDREXB       | uint8_t  __LDREXB (uint8_t \*addr)  |
| STREX        | uint32_t __STREXW (uint32_t value, uint32_t \*addr) |
| STREXH       | uint32_t __STREXH (uint16_t value, uint16_t \*addr) |
| STREXB       | uint32_t __STREXB (uint8_t value, uint8_t \*addr)   |
| CLREX        | void __CLREX (void)                 |
```

For single core CPUs and a bare metal single thread, there is no reason for an atomic increment (most drivers won't want an atomic increment).  For bit fields shared with interrupts, it can be important to atomically RMW (read-modify-write) atomically.  If you have an RTOS with scheduling, the scheduler **MUST** perform a `CRLEX()` on a context switch.  You can also use 'single reader/single writer' structures such as a ring buffer/fifo without resorting to atomics.  However, I assume you have the knowledge and need to have these primitives.

I would use either C++ or the generated code to confirm a 'C' equivalent.

See: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:4),source:%27%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A%0Astd::atomic%3Cint%3E+id%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+create_id()+%7B%0A++++return+id%2B%2B%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:carmg1220,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3++-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-x+c%2B%2B+-mcpu%3Dcortex-m4%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27ARM+gcc+12.2+(linux)+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) to process this [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206861/atomic-increment-and-return-counter) for some assembler,

```
create_id():
        ldr     r3, =ID
        dmb     ish
.L2:
        ldrex   r0, [r3]
        adds    r2, r0, #1
        strex   r1, r2, [r3]
        cmp     r1, #0
        bne     .L2
        dmb     ish
        bx      lr
```

This gives,

```
void atomic_inc(uint32_t *val)
{
   DMB();
   do {
      uint32_t tmp = LDREX(val);
      tmp++;
   } while(STREX(tmp,val));
   DMB();
}
```

For a CMSIS 'C' implementation.  I would just use the C++ atomics and expose them as `extern "C"`.  There would be no overhead for object files that are just using the *atomic* C++ primitive and I would trust (and verify) the compiler.  Lots of smart people have worked on making it correct.

You probably don't need the DMB() for non-SMP systems, but it is not that harmful unless performance is a must.  As you can see, the loop could lock for eternity.  You may wish to insert a retry counter depending on your application space and design criteria.

Comment: Reserve granules for Cortex-M are typically the entire address space as they do not have a cache.

Comment: Stackoverflow tables do not seem to work.  Feel free to edit this post if you know how to fix the table.

Comment: Why do you think there is no need for an atomic inc. Unless it is a local variable that only lives in a register an inc is also a read-modify-write.

Comment: @Martin_from_K For a single task and driver, there are often single-reader/single-writer structures that can work.  I don't know enough about the system/architecture.  It is quite possible that you need them. All I was saying is that some thought could be given to alternatives.  Too often people will think they need `atomic_inc()` when there are other structures that will work.

Comment: As an example, most registers have an alias with 'write one to clear' (W1C).  The `ATOMIC_MODIFY_REG()`  is a bit of a kludge.  You need your interrupt to support `clrex`; I think that the Cortex-M may do this by default.  However, there can be options to alter the Cortex-M interrupt behaviour.  I would trust bit-banding and/or a (W1C) register much more than 'ldrex/strex' pair and the system will work more effectively.  However, it is possible that it is the only mechanism available.  It is generally better than masking interrupts. (and this case is **NOT** `atomic_inc()`).